# PGN Viewer for blog

Tags: pgn, chess-blog

I'm looking for a decent PGN game viewer for my blog, where I post annotated games, instead of just writing down the notation I want to have a visual PGN viewer. Can anyone recommend any nice PGN viewers for blogs? Thank you.

Comment: I think many similar questions has  been asked, the question I linked to is worth looking at, particularly http://chessmicrobase.com

Comment: We are using pgn4web for local tournament website. http://lorchess.ru/2014/07/02/iVS-vs-Magian/

Comment: Yes! pgn4web seems to be the ideal PGN viewer, thank you Kakadu!